# Linux / pacman mirrors / when editing ones' mirrorlist [ vi /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist ]

Tags: arch-linux, repository

Why am I seeing the $ signs within the path?

Example:

```
Server = http://il.us.mirror.archlinux-br.org/$repo/os/$arch
```

Answer (score 1):

`man pacman.conf` explains these are variables so you can use the same url for different repos and different architectures. Use `/\$repo` in man (i.e the pager: less) to find the place.